# Are Pay For Solutions acceptable? Or should solutions be Open as well?

Tags: discussion

A previous question asked about Open Data tools. I would like to expand this question and ask if Pay for tools are acceptable answers to these questions? Pay for data is clearly never a solution to an open data question. But I feel that pay for solutions are not the type of answers askers are looking for either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can appreciate the philosophical parallels between Open Data and providing free and open software, but supporting or even touting the Open Source movement is frankly outside the purview of this site.

You are certainly free to ***prefer* answers** that provide free and open source solutions, but I don't think you can reasonably make it a policy of this site to ban legitimate Open Data tools that don't happen to be free.